# React include external CSS or JS in index.html using .env files

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to add css and js to the react project that are hosted elsewhere, but would like to include them using configurations that are in an .env.prod and .env.stg files

Is there a way to get this working? is there a better approach?

index.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="%REACT_APP_URL_CSS"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="%REACT_APP_URL_JS"></script>
    </body>
    <html>
```